# What is mp4v and mp4a?

Tags: video, streaming

When playing a MP4 file VLC tells me the video and audio codecs are mp4v and mp4a. The quality is good at low bitrates. However, the [MP4 Streaming Faq](http://all-streaming-media.com/streaming-media-faq/faq-mp4-streaming.htm) tells me that mp4v means raw MPEG4 streams. What does this mean? It clearly isn't unencoded video.

Answer (score 6):

VLC is telling you the truth - it looks to me (without actually seeing the file) that your MP4 file is a MPEG-4 container with MPEG-4 codecs being used for the audio and video.

[MPEG-4](http://wiki.videolan.org/MP4) is ***both*** a [container](http://wiki.videolan.org/MP4#Container) and a [codec](http://wiki.videolan.org/MP4#Codecs):

> MPEG-4 is a form of MPEG encoding. It
> is a flexible audio and video
> compression format. The format
> describes audio and video compression,
> with a container format for streaming
> across networks and saving to disk. It
> also contains optional extra features,
> including DRM and subtitles. These
> extra features are only included in
> software if needed. MPEG-4 can provide
> better quality than MPEG-2 at low
> bitrates.
>
> MPEG-4 audio is an advanced, complicated audio format. It includes AAC for high bitrates, multilingual tracks, text-to-speech modes for very low bitrates, the ability to synthesize instrumental sounds (similar to MIDI), and more.

Video:

> **mp4v**
>
> This is a video codec. 
> This codec can be
> used inside the MPEG-4 containers.
> This codec is from the [ffmpeg](http://wiki.videolan.org/FFMPEG) module.

Audio:

> **mp4a**
>
> This is an audio codec.
> This codec can
> be used inside the MPEG-4 containers.
> This codec is from the [ffmpeg](http://wiki.videolan.org/FFMPEG) module.

If we were talking about the MP4 container, you could see these types of codecs in them:

> **Accepted video codecs**
> mp4v, including
> all the codecs described above
>  mpgv
> MJPG
>  mjpb
>  SVQ1
>  SVQ3
>  H263
>  h264
> **Accepted
> audio codecs**
>  mp4a (is aac)
>  mpga
>  samr
> sawb
>  **Accepted subtitle codec**
>  subt

Comment: So is mp4a just another name for the aac codec?

Answer (score 2):

MP4V and MP4A stand for Mpeg 4 Video and Audio.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4):

> MPEG-4 is a patented collection of
>   methods defining compression of audio
>   and visual (AV) digital data

From [VideoLan](http://wiki.videolan.org/MP4):

> MPEG-4 specifies a range of codecs
>
> The fourccs of MPEG-4 codecs are:
>
> ```
> o DivX Codecs
>       o DIV1, div1, DIVX, divx, DX50, dx50, XVID, XviD, xvid 
> o FFMPEG MPEG-4
>       o FMP4, fmp4 
> o 3IV2, 3iv2
> o BLZ0
> o DXGM
> o HDX4, hdx4
> o M4S2, m4s2
> o MP4S, mp4s
> o MP4V, mp4v
> o RMP4
> o SEDG
> o SMP4
> o UMP4
> o WV1F
> o XVIX
> ```

For better clarification of actual codecs used try:

[MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en)

or

[GraphEdit](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/GraphEdit)

Comment: So mp4v indicates that something is an MPEG4 video stream without disclosing the actual codec used? Or is mp4v a codec itself?

Comment: it would appear that your first statement is correct. Open the file in MediaInfo to confirm.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct - MP4 is both a container AND a codec (see my answer for the gory details). VLC is telling you about the codecs being used.

Comment: Well, I learnt something today then! ;)