# What is the relation between the mp4v codec and the H.264 format?

Tags: video, streaming

This question is a follow-up to my previous question: [What is mp4v and mp4a?](https://superuser.com/questions/118212/what-is-mp4v-and-mp4a)

I understand that mp4v is a codec used within MPEG-4 containers. H264 is a also a codec that can be be used in an MPEG-4 container.

In my tests both H.264 and mpv4 are able to produce similar quality (I tested with GStreamer's x264enc and ffmpeg_mpeg4 components.)

So are there any key differences between the algorithms used. Or is mp4v just another name for H.264?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just to clear things up a bit.  mp4v is not really anything.  It is used in VLC to represent MPEG-4 Part 2 video, but in a technical sense is nothing.

MPEG-4 is the general name for a set of specifications defined by [ISO/IEC 14496](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpeg4).  There are several parts to this specification.  These are the relevant parts:

- [Part 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_2) - Commonly known as *MPEG-4 Video*, is a video compression format.
- [Part 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_3) - Commonly known as *MPEG-4 Audio*, is and audio compression format.
- [Part 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) - Commonly known as *H264* or *MPEG-4 AVC*, is also a video compression format.
- [Part 14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) - Commonly known as *MP4*, is a container format.

H.264 is typically considered to be the *better* for video compression.  It contains several features that MPEG-4 video does not including those [listed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Features).

The biggest difference you will typically see is file size.  H.264 will typically be able to compress video at a much lower bitrate than the standard MPEG-4 codec.  You should be able to get comparable quality video with much smaller file sizes.

Answer (score 1):

MPEG-4 specifies several different video (and audio) codecs. One video codec described is H.264, but not the only one.

So what VLC calls mp4v is probably one of MPEG-4's other video codecs. I didn't find anything about it in VLC's docs, so you'll probably have to dig into the source to find out which one.

It might be the codec described in Part 2 of the MPEG-4 spec.